# Swift Chaining Commands

Tags: swift, casting, chaining

I'm attempting to chain some commands with casts in swift. Anyone know why the below happens? The variable assignment portion works fine, but if I try to chain them together, it produces compile errors that seem unfixable.

```
var tempArr = JSONDict["years"]! as [AnyObject]
var tempDict = tempArr[0] as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
var tempString = tempDict["year"]! as String
var tempInt = tempString.toInt()
var year = (((JSONDict["years"]! as [AnyObject])[0] as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)["year"] as String).toInt()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `!` after `["year"]`

```
 var year = (((JSONDict["years"]! as [AnyObject])[0] as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)["year"]! as String).toInt()
```